# Integrate Moodle and .net 1.1 application to single log on

Tags: .net-1.1, moodle

My situation is, I have a .net 1.1 application to provide enrollment of courses, and some courses are provided by a moodle site. So when the user enrolls a course and he will be provided the URL link to moodle. But moodle requires the user to log on again. How can I implement a single log on?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Moodle are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to alter moodle's login.php to look for a currently logged in session from the .NET application. This approach is described in detail on the following blog:

http://www.kassblog.com/2006/08/moodle-single-sign-on-mod/